# Populate textbox based on Combobox value from a Table - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, excel-tables

I have a table containing 6 columns, I am using one of its column to populate a combobox. The userform has textbox which I want to fill based on the combobox value.
Code for populating combobox:

```
Public tbl As ListObject 
Set tbl = sh.ListObjects("Table1")
combobox.list = tbl.ListColumns("ORDER NO").DataBodyRange.value
```

Table Structure:
[image]

I want the "Party" column to be populated based on "Order No" column. Code that I tried for achieving the result:

```
Private Sub combobox_Change()
  Me.textbox.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(me.combobox.value, tbl, 4, False)
End Sub
```

I am getting "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheeFunction class" error

Comment: Vlookup will need to work on tbl's range.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.databodyrange

Comment: When post your code, do not post only portions, please. Is `Public tbl As ListObject` on the declaration area of a standard module? Now, did you try `Me.textbox.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(me.combobox.value, tbl.DataBodyRange, 5, False)`? If it does not work, what kind of data exist in the first column (you need to match the format there with the format taken from Combo). Then, you must know that `Vlookup` **will return the first occurrence in the table**. Is that what you want? I remember your first question, where required the unique values...

Comment: @FaneDURU Yes, I have declared tbl as Public. Yes correct it  is related to unique values question and I want that. I have tried your suggestion but its not working. I think so the problem is, for Vlookup to work, the first column of the range should contain the Search column and in my case its the 3rd column. So how would I shift the column in the variable `tbl` at the first column?

Comment: What does "to work" mean? This does not tell us anything... Do you receive an error? If yes, what error? How to contain **the Search column like the 3rd one**, since the combo is loaded with data from the first one? Do you mean the column where to return from? Even so, you did not answer my clarification question regarding the data type and the format... If you do not help us to help you, we are not the mind readers.

Comment: @FaneDuruI have edited the question for more clarity

Comment: So, you don't need the unique values, any more. Then, **`Vlookup` works only if the column to search the lookup value is the first one**. Now, what does **"Party" column to be populated based on "Order No" column** mean? Isn't it already populated? If not, to be populated with what? Do you want returning from it, in fact? If no unique values anymore, and you want returning from it, the combo `listIndex` property will do the job as you want. But you must clarify what really you want. I must confess, I still cannot understand that...

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry if you are still confused. Let me try to explain in detail. I have a userform which has textboxes and a combobox. Combobox contains a dropdown list which are unique obtained from the above table. When I select an item from the dropdown list of the combobox, some of the textbox should get populated from the table. So for example, in the userforms' combobox, I selected "CA94" so the textbox "Party" would get populated with "S1".

Comment: I am not sure I am confused... I become confused when try understanding your problem. Between **"Party" column** and a text box named  "Party" is a huge difference. So you want returning from column "Party", as I supposed in my previous column. Now, you talk about **dropdown list which are unique**, even if your updated code does not load it in the form you say.  Aren't different "Party" values for the same "Order No"? If not it starts to become a little clearer, but you do not say anything about what I stated regarding `Vlookup` its the need about the first column in the range to search...